# Facebook login with Ruby on Rails using omniauth-facebook gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, omniauth-facebook

I'm developing a RoR application with Facebook login.  I have two types of user (i.e. the admins and the users), and both can login with Facebook.

I want to redirect the admin to a specific action on controller and the client to another action. So I have tried this:

My routes:

```
get 'auth/:provider/callback/admin', to: 'sessions#create_admin'
get 'auth/:provider/callback/client', to: 'sessions#create_client'
```

My controller:

```
def create_admin
  auth = env["omniauth.auth"]
  user = Spree::User.find_by(email: auth.info.email)

  redirect_from_oauth(user) and return if user.present?

  user = Spree::User.from_omniauth(auth, "admin")
  redirect_to setup_step1_path(uid: user.id, t: user.confirmation_token)
end

def create_client
  auth = env["omniauth.auth"]
  user = Spree::User.find_by(email: auth.info.email)
  user = Spree::User.from_omniauth(auth, "client") unless user.present?

  redirect_back_or_default(root_path)
end
```

My javascript:

```
$('.facebook-btn').click(function(e) {
  var userType = $(this).data('type');

  return FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
      return window.location = '/auth/facebook/callback/' + userType;
    }
  }, {scope: 'email,public_profile', return_scopes: true})
});
```

But gives the error for both:

```
undefined method `info' for nil:NilClass
```

When I remove from my routes the user type, like below, it works.

```
get 'auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#create'
```

What's the better way to do that? Can I send params to omaniauth?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using **Devise** for authentication and your model User have **admin** and **client** attributes, you can do the following, on `application_controller.rb`:

```
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    if resource.admin?
      your_admin_path_here
    elsif resource.client?
      your_client_path_here
    end
  end
```